# SSHed into my Vagrant virtual machine to run a python script...but the python script doesn't work unless I'm in the VM itself

Tags: python, selenium, ssh, vagrant

I have a Vagrant virtual machine that I use for running automated tests. When I vagrant up and open up the console in my virtual machine, I'm able to start my tests with a simple command on the command line. After SSHing into that virtual machine and running the same exact script from the same exact directory, I'm getting errors with regards to modules not existing and certain files not existing. What might be the case?

I used nano to make a random txt file and surely enough I saw that the txt file appeared in my SSH terminal when I looked in the directory where I placed the txt. What could be different about the environment from SSH's perspective? Why would executing the same python script from the VM's terminal and from the SSH terminal have drastically different results?

I'm using the robots framework and selenium for my testing. The python script I'm executing from the command line kicks off those tests.

Comment: Run `which python` in both environments. Are the results identical?

Comment: Nope! Great catch. When running it from the SSH console, the result is /usr/bin/python. When running it from the Vagrant VM console, the result is /home/vagrant/regression_venv/bin/python. So I'm guessing I need to change the SSH console's python to be the one that is in the path I see in the Vagrant VM console.

Comment: After adding the other python directory to my path, I'm able to get the results I wanted. Can you write your response as an answer so I can upvote it and accept it? @Robᵩ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't using the same Python executable in the two environments. For some reason, your vagrant console is using a [virtual environment](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/).

When you SSH into your VM, run this command before executing your test script:

```
source /home/vagrant/regression_venv/bin/activate
```